# Select all rows from MySQL table with non-existent relation as empty cell

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, left-join

If I had for example two tables called 'teachers' and 'lessons' and 'lessons' has a foreign key 'teacher_ID' referring to its counterpart in the 'teachers' table, then how would I select **all** rows from teacher with **all** of their corresponding lessons with an empty cell if no lesson is connected to them? I  only was able to make MySQL show me the teachers that **have** one or more lessons attached.

Is this even possible without LEFT JOIN? I couldn't find anything on Google...

**EDIT**
I was interested in the mechanics of the LEFT JOIN keyword. But since there doesn't seem to be an alternative I'd say *case closed*.

Comment: What's wrong with a LEFT JOIN...?

Comment: Just use `LEFT JOIN`. The mechanic is explain in the manual http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: please mark your answer as correct if you think this is the right answer for your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is using `LEFT JOIN`. This way if not match you will get `(teacher_id), null`

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all the rows from the left table (teachers), even if there are no matches in the right table (lessons).

```
 SELECT teacher.teacher_ID, lesson.lesson_ID
 FROM teachers
 LEFT JOIN lessons
   ON teacher.teacher_ID = lesson.teacher_ID
```

If you want to emulate `LEFT JOIN` first use `JOIN` to find the element with match. And use `UNION` to add the rest with a value of `NULL`

```
 SELECT teacher.teacher_ID, lessons.lesson_ID
 FROM teachers
 JOIN lessons
   ON teacher.teacher_ID = lessons.teacher_ID

 UNION

 SELECT teacher.teacher_ID, null as lesson_ID
 FROM teachers
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                    FROM lessons 
                    WHERE lessons.teacher_id = teacher.teacher_id)
```